# Linkedin Rails (403): Access to posting shares denied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When using the Linkedin gems for ruby on rails and using the Share api call encountered an error.

> (403): Access to posting shares denied

I followed the tutorial in the github omniauth-linkedin.

this is my function for the linkedin.

```
def self.post_status(token,secret)
    client = LinkedIn::Client.new('xxxx', 'xxxx')
    client.authorize_from_access(token,secret)
    client.add_share({:comment => "blah"})
end
```

this is the full stacktrace

> linkedin (1.1.0) lib/linked_in/helpers/request.rb:52:in `raise_errors'
>   linkedin (1.1.0) lib/linked_in/helpers/request.rb:22:in`post'
>   linkedin (1.1.0) lib/linked_in/api/share_and_social_stream.rb:95:in `add_share'
>   app/models/linkedin_linked.rb:21:in`post_status'
>   app/controllers/post_social_controller.rb:5:in `post'
>   actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in`send_action'
>   actionpack (4.2.6) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
>   actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in`process_action'
>   actionpack (4.2.6) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
>   activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in`call'
>   activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
>   activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:555:in`block (2 levels) in compile'
>   activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
>   activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in`call'
>   activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `__run_callbacks__'
>   activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in`_run_process_action_callbacks'
>   activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
>   actionpack (4.2.6) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in`process_action'
>   actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
>   actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in`block in process_action'
>   activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
>   activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in`instrument'
>   activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
>   actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in`process_action'
>   actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
>   activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in`process_action'
>   actionpack (4.2.6) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
>   actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in`process'
>   actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
>   actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in`dispatch'
>   actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:237:in `block in action'
>   actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:74:in`call'
>   actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:74:in `dispatch'
>   actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:43:in`serve'
>   actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
>   actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in`each'
>   actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
>   actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:817:in`call'
>   omniauth (1.3.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in `call!'
>   omniauth (1.3.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in`call'
>   omniauth (1.3.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in `call!'
>   omniauth (1.3.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in`call'
>   omniauth (1.3.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in `call!'
>   omniauth (1.3.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in`call'
>   omniauth (1.3.1) lib/omniauth/builder.rb:63:in `call'
>   rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in`call'
>   rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:38:in `call'
>   rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in`call'
>   actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
>   actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in`call'
>   rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
>   rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in`call'
>   actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
>   activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in`call'
>   activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:653:in `call'
>   activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/migration.rb:377:in`call'
>   actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
>   activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in`**run_callbacks**'
>   activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_call_callbacks'
>   activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in`run_callbacks'
>   actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
>   actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in`call'
>   actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
>   actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in`call'
>   web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
>   web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in`catch'
>   web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
>   actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in`call'
>   railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
>   railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in`block in call'
>   activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
>   activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in`tagged'
>   activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
>   railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in`call'
>   actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
>   rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in`call'
>   rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
>   activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in`call'
>   rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
>   actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:120:in`call'
>   rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
>   railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in`call'
>   railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
>   rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in`call'
>   rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
>   rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in`service'
>   /home/jgeliberte/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
>   /home/jgeliberte/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in`run'
>   /home/jgeliberte/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:294:in `block in start_thread'

Hope you can help me regarding my problem.

Comment: Any hopes on finding how to solve this? anyone?

Comment: Did you solve this? No matter what I do, it keeps throwing this 403 error. I've even enabled w_share on LinkedIn also. :/